# post request always executed at last angularjs function (not executing sequentially)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am  facing an issue. i have  angularjs  function which in turn call to  another angularjs function which has post request.This post request always fire at last  when  first function ends..it is not fired sequntially.

```
   pseudo code

     $scope.fun1= function()
         {

            $scope.fun2();


            console.log("after call to  fun2"); // execute before fun2
         }

   $scope.fun2=function()
        {

          $http.post(valid request);///this always executed at last..means at end of  function 1...no matter  at what position i call it
       }
```

Please someone  explain me this behaviour..any workaround for  this...i want to  execute all http  request sequentially.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: fun2 is an async function - once it's called the rest of your code will continue to run while the post is in progress.

Comment: @tymeJV i want to suspend other activity unless i get response from fun2..how to achieve this ?

Comment: Doesn't demonstrate minimal understanding of Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use promises. A promise will give you a variable on which you can call register a piece of code to be called based on some event happening in the future - in this case, $http.post() returning. 
You can read more about promises [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and take a look at your modified pseudo code below.

```
//       pseudo code

     $scope.fun1= function()
         {

            $scope.fun2().then(function(data) {
                 console.log("after call to  fun2"); // execute before fun2
             });



         }

   $scope.fun2=function() {
           var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                url: "whatever/something",
                method: "POST",
                params: {// if you need params}
            }).success(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function () {
                deferred.resolve(null);
            });
            return deferred.promise;

       }
```

Comment: http request is not executing..if i  use above code.check both success and error bock..

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a synchronous call.  While that is possible with the XmlHttpRequest object, angular $http doesn't support that currently and it is considered poor programming practice to freeze the web page while waiting for a response from the server.  If you want the console log to execute after the post, you can return the result of the call to `.post()` and use the `.success()` method to do something after it is complete [(***PLNKR***)](http://plnkr.co/edit/BOh0J58b0ujnhM8CnrGo?p=preview):

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

var ctrl = app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.fun1 = function() {
    $scope.fun2().success(function(data) {
      console.log('after call to fun2');
    });
  };

  $scope.fun2 = function() {
    var result = $http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
      console.log('fun2 got', JSON.stringify(data));
    });
    return result; // still has .success() and .error() functions on it
  };
})
```